# How to make additional paragraph commands that use sectioning counters?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, paragraphs, counters

I would like to be able to use the following additional (new) commands: `\sparagraph`, `\ssparagraph`, `\sssparagraph`. All of these will use the `\paragraph` formatting but, will use different counters. The `\sparagraph` will use the section label and counter. The `\ssparagraph` will use the sub section label and counter. The `\sssparagraph` will use the sub sub section label and counter.

If the chapter is 1 and the section is 1. The label for the section will be 1.1. If I followed this section with a `\sparagraph`, I would want the paragraph to start with 1.2. Formatting as the `\paragraph`, but using the section numbering, including incrementing that counter.

Comment: What is the difference between `\sparagraph` and `\subsection`? Do you just want to rename them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, using the standard sectional definitions via `\@startsection`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\sparagraph{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\ssparagraph{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\sssparagraph{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Allow numbering up to \subsubsection or \sssparagraph
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\sparagraph{An sparagraph}
\ssparagraph{An ssparagraph}
\ssparagraph{Another ssparagraph}
\sssparagraph{An sssparagraph}

\sparagraph{Another sparagraph}
\ssparagraph{A ssparagraph}
\sssparagraph{An sssparagraph}
\sssparagraph{An sssparagraph}
\end{document}
```

`\sparagraph` and friends are setup using the `section`|`subsection`|`subsubsection` counter, and is also set at that level (1, 2 or 3, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

ConTeXt provides a `\definehead` command to define new section heads.

```
\definehead
  [paragraph] % ConTeXt doesn't define \paragraph.
  [subsubsubsection] % It uses \subsubsubsection instead.

\definehead
  [sparagraph]
  [section]

\definehead
  [ssparagraph]
  [subsection]

\definehead
  [sssparagraph]
  [subsubsection]

\setuphead
  [sparagraph,ssparagraph,sssparagraph,paragraph]
  [alternative=text,
   style=bold]
```

All `\define<something>` commands in ConTeXt follow the same syntax:

```
\define<....>
      [<name>]
      [<parent>]
      [<options>]
```

I define `\sparagraph` etc to inherit all their settings from the corresponding section command, and then overwrite the `style` and `alternative` settings so that they match that of `paragraph`.

Comment: Probably LaTeX should have used `\subsubsubsection` too, as `\paragraph` causes all sorts of confusion :-)

Comment: At `subsubsubsubsection` (the default section depth in ConTeXt), the subsub alternative also starts to get confusing! ConTeXt also defines `\startsectionlevel` ... `\stopsectionlevel` set of macros, that can be nested to increment the section depth.